# Ubuntu 20.04.3 taking up too much space?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, disk-usage, df

I am new to linux OS and so my apologies if this is disjointed or a stupid/basic question. I am running into an issue where I had allocated about 50gb for this installation of ubuntu (20.04.3) (running in dualboot with Windows11) and suddenly only have ~20gb left somehow.

When I check df -h it says I am using 40% of my space but I literally only use this for a dev bootcamp I joined, and have no large files on here. I also used ncdu and got the results noted below. How can I reclaim that "used" space?

EDIT: `sudo du -xd1` results:

128 /tmp

10952   /etc

4   /mnt

293236  /opt

2798880 /home

108 /root

16  /lost+found

7728404 /usr

3604944 /var

4   /cdrom

4   /srv

8   /media

156972  /boot

16690820    /

[df-h results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXB67.png)

[ncdu results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmEFq.png)

[hdd space remaining](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rKbu1.png)

Comment: from my googling before posting most people said a fresh install should take ~5gb though?

Comment: In the future, please copy and paste text instead of providing screen shots.  [You can put them in code blocks](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting).  If you do provide screen shots, display them as images instead of providing links.

Comment: You need to run `ncdu` as `ncdu /` to start with *all* of the disk usage, also `du` is easier to copy-paste from.  [Edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1392186/edit) into your question the copy-pasted output of `sudo du -xd1 /`.

Comment: Hit the Super key (Win Logo) then type `disk` , then select `Disk Usage Ana...` - click about in it.

Comment: A basic installation is nearer 10 GB than 5GB. You have nearly 4 GB of dot files, you have added an unknown number of applications that may account for most of those dot files. You will probably have a swap file that looks like it may be 10 GB. You may have done a number of updates and so have old packages and kernel’s lying around. None of this is unreasonable usage but have a look at the following tutorial. https://itsfoss.com/free-up-space-ubuntu-linux/  It covers several places to look to free up space and is worth following from time to time

Comment: Thanks for your replies guys! I copy-pasted the results of sudo du -xd1 / and according to the disk usage analysis I have a couple of issues that I can see:

under "var/log/journal" I have a 2.5gb file that's just a bunch of random letters and numbers. Is this file important / can I delete it?